# Error: The return type 'Timer' isn't a 'Future<void>'

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Estoy usando flutter para un proyecto y tengo este fragmento de código:

```
bool _isLoading = false;

Future<Null> fetchData() async {
    _isLoading = true;
    setState(() {
      final duracion = new Duration(seconds: 2);
      return new Timer(duracion, respuestaHTTP); //<---Error en esta linea
    });
  }
```

pero me arroja este error:

**The return type 'Timer' isn't a 'Future', as required by the closure's context.**

¿Cómo lo soluciono?

> **Nota:** Para el proyecto estoy viendo videos pero en los videos no ocurre el error.

Comment: agrega más código, el error es claro, dice que Timer no es del tipo Future, tu método empieza con Future<Null> fetchdata, pero tu estás usando ... return new Timer. 
Agrega el código que llama a `fetchData`

Answer (score 0):

Problema es que Timer una clase que ejecuta una funcion en un tiempo determinado por ti en duration y no devuelve un valor en el callback. Esto es lo que puedes hacer para arreglar el error:

```
bool _isLoading = false;

  void fetchData() async { // void por que no se retorna un valor
    _isLoading = true;
    setState(() {
      final duracion = new Duration(seconds: 2);
      Timer(duracion, respuestaHTTP); // Y aqui se hara el request en 2 segundos
    });
  }
```

Si ya quieres que fetchData retorne un valor, ya se tendria que hacer algo diferente, como esto:

```
      bool _isLoading = false;
    
      Future<Map<String, dynamic>> fetchData() async { // Future por que se retornara en algun punto en el futuro
        _isLoading = true;
        return await respuestaHTTP;  // respuestaHTTP tiene que ser una funcion que retorne un valor Future de tipo Map<String, dynamic> 
      // si es asi que se obtiene la peticion desde el servidor, puede que varie el tipo de dato dependiendo que se quiere recibir.
      }
```